# Running my app on a 2g network

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, mobile-application

**Description of my app :**

I have an application built in simple HTML/CSS/Javascript-Jquery using PHONEGAP !! My app has a WCFService running on a server that does the communication with the DB.I have called the WCFService from my app using AJAX call !!!

Now that all is set and i have built the application and tested it on my mobile devices(ios/android/blackberry)!!

***!!..BINGO..!!*** It worked fine while testing on WIFI connection.But when trying to connect using mobile GPRS(2g data) it fails. Should i specify any other settings to ensure my app runs on 2g network also ???

**UPDATE:- MY AJAX CODE :**

```
$.ajax({
                url: http://www.xyzftp.com/WCFService/Service1.svc/rejectrequest,
                data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {  


    $.each(data.GetRejectedRequestsMethodResult,function(key,val){

                //my code on success//


                error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {                       
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            }); // end $.ajax
```

Comment: would you share your ajax code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no seperate settings for that..try to detect your network connection type using the [connection API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html).make sure that u have a considerable speed and ensure that u have enabled mobile data..
it should work..